# flask how authenticate login users with existing mssql users?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have to migrate my delphi existing project to Flask with SQLAlchemy and all the users-loggins authenticate with SQL Server 2008r2 and my question is How do i authenticate or validate the user/password with Flask stored in SQL Server?

Comment: For authentication you can use `Flask-Login` package. You can even use JWT to authenticate the user. https://medium.com/@riken.mehta/full-stack-tutorial-3-flask-jwt-e759d2ee5727, this link will be helpful for you.

Comment: This mega tutorial will help you a lot, also in following best practices: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database